# Why can't I see subfolders in a shared folder I have Read and List Folder Content permission for?

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, network-share

Not sure if Microsoft have changes something or not.

I have a shared folder called **Users** on a server. Each user in my domain has a sub-folder within it, lets call one **SmithJohn**. So the structure is **\\Server\Users\SmithJohn**.

Everyone has **Read** access to the **\\Server\Users** folder but only the user and people they nominate have **Read** or **Modify** permissions to the **SmithJohn** folder.

I'm sure that in Windows Server 2003 people in **\\Server\Users** could see all the folders it contained, regardless of the permissions they had to the **SmithJohn** folder. On this 2008 Server they only see folders they have permission for. It this behaviour intended or have I got permissions on the Users folder wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like ABE (Access Based Enumeration) is enabled on the Share. With ABE enabled on the share you'll only see objects in the share that you have NTFS Allow permissions on.

Comment: Glad to help...